# Eloquent - laravel. Get rows based on input user. Get all when input empty

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying get fetch results on the information a user gives me in a form.
In the form the user can select a `$city`, `$skillLevel`, `province` and a `$category`.

obviously, when the form is left empty, it will return all rows. when every field is filled in, except for the `$city`, it will return results with his chosen options, from every city.

I'm still new with eloquent and I'm stuck on this for quite a while now. Hopefully someone can help me out.

This is the controller that calls the function in the Model to retrieve the results:

```
/**
* Returns all vacatures
 * @param string $city
 * @param string $skillLevel
 * @param string $province
 * @param string $category
 */
public function vacatureOverzicht($city, $skillLevel, $province, $category)
{
    $vacatures = $vacatures = with(new Vacature)->getVacatures($city, $skillLevel, $province, $category);

    return View::make('vacatures')->with('vacatures', $vacatures);
}
```

This is my Model function (obviously still empty):

```
/**
     * Return results with options given by user
     *
     * @param $city
     * @param $skillLevel
     * @param $province
     * @param $category
     */
    public function getVacatures($city, $skillLevel, $province, $category) {
          $vacatures = DB:table('vacatures')
                        // Do stuff to select rows
                       ->get();
          return $vacatures;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing them in one by one, create an array and pass that in:

```php
public function getVacatures(array $filter = [])
{
    $columns = [
        'city',
        'province',
        'category',
        'skill_level',
    ];

    $query = $this->newQuery();

    foreach ($filters as $column => $value)
    {
        if ( ! in_array($column, $columns)) continue;

        $query->where($key, $value);
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```

Comment: So in the controller I put them in an array, and when i call the model function in pass the array?

Comment: @SupSonツ - Yes. That way you don't end up with a call like this `foo(null, null, 'Hong Kong', null)`. Does that sound like fun to you?